# Unable to Tag IAM Users created in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm writing a CloudFormation template to create, some policies, groups and users. So far I'm able to do all that, but I want to go a step further and tag those brand new users, I have googled for how to add tag to the users (under resources section) without any success and if I put `Tags` under `Properties` CloudFormation complain about it because `Tags` is an invalid key.

I know I can tag users through the AWS management console, but how can I do it through CloudFormation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As at the time of writing this response (July 2019), Tags are not supported in the 
[`AWS::IAM::User`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-user.html) element:

```
Type: AWS::IAM::User
Properties: 
  Groups: 
    - String
  LoginProfile: 
    LoginProfile
  ManagedPolicyArns: 
    - String
  Path: String
  PermissionsBoundary: String
  Policies: 
    - Policy
  UserName: String
```

There are some suggested workarounds on Reddit: [Tagging AWS::IAM::Role in CloudFormation : aws](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/ag4lv0/tagging_awsiamrole_in_cloudformation/) (Role is similar to User)